# how to get name of a accessible parent(panel) in swing?

Tags: java, swing, parent-child

When i click the button, it will print the accessible parent name. is there any way is to do that?.

I have tried some codes, but its printing null.
Can anyone point out my mistake.

```
    Container c  = cancel.getParent();
    System.out.println("Parent Name = "+c.getName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not determine you problem because I didn't see your full code, but try the following code:

```
JButton cancel = new JButton("AAAA");
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setName("Panel p");
p.add(cancel);
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(p);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(cancel.getParent().getName());
```

This will print the "Panel p" as the parent of cancel button.

I think this is what you want.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, this one is fine.

Comment: When an answer fit your question, typically you accept it or vote it up or both.

Answer (score 1):

For the `getName()` to work, you should have called the `c.setName()` earlier and set a proper name to it.

Otherwise it would just return the default value which is `null` in most cases (including yours) and if `c` was a `JFrame` it would by default return something like `Frame0` etc...

Comment: I have a jpanel as a parent, the panel name is Test, suppose i want to get the name of a panel, which is the easy way.

Comment: How do you say the panel's name is Test?? Have you called `panel.setName("Test")` in your code???

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by  rename, but for getName() to work you should have called setName() on it when you created the panel...

Comment: @ Abishek Manoharan i did mistake, now i am setting the name to the panel using panel.setName() function.  Thank you.